# Coding (input) is not working in Terminal

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm learning how to use "input" function to interact with data input. I'm aware this set of coding may not work in Sublime Text but it is also not working in Terminal.

I did it in this way
1. Write the codes in Sublime Text
2. Save the file and open again by Python Launcher 3
3. No issues with first 2 lines codes. When I input something, the program stopped.
4. There is no issues when I run a similar program with numbers (int)

**These are the codes written in Sublime Text:**

```
prompt = "\nTell me something, and I will repeat it back to you:"
prompt += "\nEnter 'complete' to end the program. "
message = ""
while message != 'complete':
    message = input(prompt)
    print(message)
```

**And This is error message shown in Terminal:**

```
Lins-MacBook-Pro:~ linyang$ cd '/Users/linyang/Desktop/python_work/' && 
'/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/linyang/Desktop/python_work/parrot.py'  && echo 
Exit status: $? && exit 1

Tell me something, and I will repeat it back to you:
Enter 'complete' to end the program. complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/linyang/Desktop/python_work/parrot.py", line 5, in <module>
    message = input(prompt)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'complete' is not defined
Lins-MacBook-Pro:python_work linyang$
```

**This is another set of codes written in Sublime Text:**

```
number = input("May I know how many people will dine? ")
number = int(number)

if number > 8:
    print("Sorry, there is no enough seats.")
else:
    print("Seats available!")
```

**It works perfect in Terminal:**

```
cd '/Users/linyang/Desktop/python_work/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  
'/Users/linyang/Desktop/python_work/even_or_odd.py'  && echo Exit status: $? 
&& exit 1
Lins-MacBook-Pro:~ linyang$ cd '/Users/linyang/Desktop/python_work/' && 
'/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/linyang/Desktop/python_work/even_or_odd.py'  && 
echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
May I know how many people will dine? 6
Seats available!
Exit status: 0
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Please provide your code/errors/inputs/outputs as text in the question itself instead of linking images

Comment: Please *never* post images of text. It means we have to painstakingly transcribe your code before we can try it ourselves, or—more likely—we don't bother and look at another question  instead.

Comment: Question revised.

Comment: You aren't trying to run that on Python 2, are you?

Comment: No. I was trying to run it on Python 3. Or I have to run the codes step by step on Terminal (Python 2 or 3)?